# function returning pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I was not clear about my issue, so I am reviewing the question. I have a function manipulating a generic dataframe (it removes and renames columns and records):

```
def manipulate_df(df_local):
    df_local.rename(columns={'A': 'grouping_column'}, inplace = True)
    df_local.drop('B', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df_local.drop(df.query('grouping_column not in (\'1\', \'0\')').index, inplace = True)
    df_local = df_local.groupby(['grouping_column'])['C'].sum().to_frame().reset_index().copy()

    print("this is what I need:")
    print(df_local)
```

this manipulating function is called in the main body of my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
manipulate_df(df)
print("this is what I got:")
print(df.head(5))
```

Upon execution of the blocks ahead, this is the Output I am getting:

```
this is what I need:
   grouping_column   C
0                0  72
1                1  29
this is what I got:
   grouping_column  C
0                0  5
1                0  5
2                0  4
3                1  9
6                0  5
```

While the dropping and the filters are retained, the grouping is not. 
How can I achieve the manipulating function to actually group the dataframe?

Thanks again and apologize for my previous confusing post.

Comment: Ciao Giuseppe, do you mind to share a bit of your dataframe and write your function properly? It's not clear what it returns. Grazie.

Comment: Ciao, I just have done it. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ciao, you just need to add `return df_local` to `manipulate_df` and then
`df_out = manipulate_df(df)`

Comment: correct, it was exactly what zipa was saying... I need to study a little bit more about variable scope.... thanks a lot. ciao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, aside from unreadable code, that you never return changes.

Take a look at this example:

```
a = 'foo'

def my_func(a):
    a = 'bar'

my_func(a)
print(a)
#foo
a = my_func(a)
#None
```

Avoiding all the scope talk, you need to return something from your function or edit the global variable:

```
a = 'foo'

def my_func():
    global a
    a = 'bar'
myfunc()
print(a)
#bar
```

Or
    a = 'foo'

```
def my_func(a):
    a = 'bar'
    return a
a = myfunc(a)
print(a)
#bar
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying and aplogise for the unreadable code... I have changed the code to `return df.groupby(['AreaName', 'AreaCode', 'CommName', 'ComCode', 'Year'])['Value'].sum().to_frame().reset_index()` but the duplicates are not deleted.

Comment: I have changed the original question so that you can replicate easily my issue. thanks again

Comment: ..and I finally understood what you were saying. Thanks, you helped me.

Comment: this really helped me! first function i've used in python, gonna be doing more of this for all my repetition